# " A new session could not be created" error is throwing when the WebdriverIO test is run

Tags: node.js, selenium, webdriver-io

I am having one test as selenium.js which is written using WebdriverIO and Node.js. When I run the test, I am getting an error as `"driver.version: unknown"`.

I have validated my System PATH variable and chrome driver version. But couldn't find out the root cause.

**selenium.js:**

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }
};

webdriverio
    .remote(options)
    .init()
    .url('http://www.google.com')
    .getTitle().then(function(title) {
        console.log('Title was: ' + title);
    })
    .end()
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

**Error:**

```
{ Error: A new session could not be created.
    at end() - C:\Projects\Testing_Tool_Evaluation\my-first-react-test\selenium.js:15:6
  details: undefined,
  message: 'Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService\nBuild info: version: \'3.13.0\', revision: \'2f0d292\', time: \'2018-06-25T15:32:19.891Z\'\nSystem info: host: \'SUARUMG-IN-LE01\', ip: \'10.0.75.1\', os.name: \'Windows 10\', os.arch: \'amd64\', os.version: \'10.0\', java.version: \'1.8.0_161\'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown',
  type: 'RuntimeError',
  seleniumStack:
   { type: 'SessionNotCreatedException',
     message: 'A new session could not be created.',
     orgStatusMessage: 'Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService\nBuild info: version: \'3.13.0\', revision: \'2f0d292\', time: \'2018-06-25T15:32:19.891Z\'\nSystem info: host: \'SUARUMG-IN-LE01\', ip: \'10.0.75.1\', os.name: \'Windows 10\', os.arch: \'amd64\', os.version: \'10.0\', java.version: \'1.8.0_161\'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown' } }
```

I can observe the below Capabilities in the selenium server after running the test

```
 Capabilities are: {
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "handlesAlerts": true,
  "javascriptEnabled": true,
  "locationContextEnabled": true,
  "loggingPrefs": {
    "browser": "ALL",
    "driver": "ALL"
  },
  "requestOrigins": {
    "url": "http:\u002f\u002fwebdriver.io",
    "version": "4.13.0",
    "name": "webdriverio"
  },
  "rotatable": true
}
```